# Confusion in writing Complementary function of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation as

$( D^{2} + a )y  = 0$ , where D  is differential operator

I have  roots of D as $\pm$ $\sqrt{a}i$

I am having confusiin in this part which is that

Should i write CF as c $cos\sqrt {a} x +  d sin\sqrt {a} x  $

Or should i write

C F as $ e^{\sqrt {a}ix}  +e^{-\sqrt {a}ix}$

I Thinkit is former ine but textbook has written latter one .I have read rules for this again , Please someoneexplain .Thanks

Comment: @Amzoti so both ways are correct for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  write both if you don't forget the constants in  $ e^{\sqrt {a}ix}  +e^{-\sqrt {a}ix}$ because
$$c_1 \cos\sqrt {a} x +  c_2 \sin\sqrt {a} x  = c_3 e^{\sqrt {a} i x}+c_4 e^{-\sqrt {a} i x}$$
with $c_1=c_3+c_4$  and $c_2=i\ (c_3-c_4)$

Comment: I think you have forgot an $i$ in the relation of the constants, $c_2=i(c_3-c_4)$.

Comment: @ mickep: You are right. I made the correction. Thank you for the remark.